# Scala.js with angular type casting

Tags: angularjs, scala, scala.js

I am trying to implement an application with Scala.JS and Angular and I am facing a problem with type casting when submitting the form.

I have the following code:

```
<div ng-controller="usersCtrl">
<form novalidate class="simple-form">
    First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="user.firstName" /><br />
    Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="user.lastName" /><br />
    E-mail: <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" /><br />
    Password: <input type="password" ng-model="user.password" /><br />
    ConfirmPassword: <input type="password" ng-model="user.passwordConfirmation" /><br />
    <input type="submit" ng-click="controller.signup(user)" value="Save" />
</form>
```

```
@JSExport
@injectable("usersCtrl")
  class UsersCtrl(
  scope: UsersScope,
  proxy: UsersServiceProxy,
  val timeout: Timeout)
extends AbstractController[UsersScope](scope) {

  @JSExport
  def signup(user: UserSignup): Future[User] = {
    proxy.signup(scope.user)
  }
}


@JSExportAll
case class UserSignup(firstName: String, lastName: String, email: String, password: String, passwordConfirmation: String)
```

But when I try to submit the form I get the following error:

```
$c_sjsr_UndefinedBehaviorError {s$1: "An undefined behavior was detected: [object Object] is not an instance of rentalot.users.UserSignup", e$1: $c_jl_ClassCastException
```

I have tried several options, including getting the user via the scope, with having a user variable defined either as an UserSignup or as UndefOf[UserSignup] but with no luck. The latter fails when I try to do scope.user.toOption.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala.JS can't automatically convert a JS Object to Scala case class. You need to define a facade. Refer to [this document.](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/interoperability/facade-types.html)
It should look something like this:

```
@js.native
trait UserSignup extends js.Object { 
  def firstName: String = js.native
  def lastName: String = js.native
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it looks promising. I am getting the following error when adding the @js.native annotation.

I am using scala.js version 0.6.11 through this project: https://github.com/greencatsoft/scalajs-angular

Comment: What error are you getting? Did you import the annotation right?

Comment: Sorry, missed to add it. The error is: type native is not a member of package scala.scalajs.js

Comment: That's very odd, can you add `import scala.scalajs.js` to your imports?

Comment: Yes, I have added that to my imports and still compains.. Not sure if it gets confused as there is a class and a method with the same name in `scala.scala.js` or something else odd happens with the dependencies.

Comment: Maybe run `sbt clean` or let your IDE re-index. This should definitely work in Scala.js `>=0.6.x`

Comment: Tried `sbt clean` and manually deleting all target directories, with no luck.. Will investigate further

Comment: It was because `scalajs-stubs` was not implementing `js.native` and I had the code in a shared folder with jvm code.